# AngularJS Select Box Tag Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, frontend

I am working on sorting blog categories by tag, and having some trouble.

Here is my markup:

```
            <div class="filter_contain">
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search Articles..." />
            <select name="tag-filter" ng-model="query">
                <option value="">All Tags</option>
                <option ng-show="(d.header.taxonomy.tag).length > 0" ng-repeat="d in blogData | unique: 'header.taxonomy.tag'" value="{[{d.header.taxonomy.tag}]}">
                    {[{d.header.taxonomy.tag.join('')}]}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <section class="blog_grid_contain">
            <!--begin blog_item-->
            <div class="blog_item" ng-repeat="d in blogData | toArray:false | filter:query" ng-show="([d.header.title, d.content] | filter:filterBySearch).length > 0">
                <div class="top_img">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
                </div>
                <div class="item_text">
                    <h3>{[{d.header.title}]}</h3>
                    <p>{[{d.content.trunc(100)}]}</p>
                    <a ng-href="insights/{[{d.header.title | slugify}]}">Read Article</a>
                    <p class="tag">{[{d.header.taxonomy.tag}]}</p>
                </div>
            </div><!--end blog_item-->
```

The all tags option seems to work fine, but the rest of the select options made all of the blog posts disapear from the DOM. I am fairly new to AngularJS, and would really appreciate any help!

(on a side note I am using TWIG hence the unusual {[{}]} )

Comment: Can your provide a piece of your `array`? Put it [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DTmPGInX9UU40zxSb7i4?p=preview).

Comment: Sure here. I have added the same json that I am working with, and updated the script file to match the script I have. I have seriously been bashing my head on this for days so ANY help to get me closer would be GREAT man!
you can find my fork to yours [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fTzX41?p=preview)

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any kind of array there... I need your array structure, 2 items of your array is enough.

Comment: @JoethaCoder , where is your json data ?

Comment: @developer033 Sorry about that! Check data.json

Comment: @tommoc see data.json

Comment: Ok, now I'm trying to understand what do you mean by *"The all tags option seems to work fine, but the rest of the select options made all of the blog posts disapear from the DOM"*..

Comment: @developer033 I just mean that when I select the "all tags" option in the select box; all of the blog posts show up for me, but when I select any of the other tags all of the blog posts are removed from the DOM. Like when I inspect there are no blog posts at all in the HTML.